# Usually, Character Creation isn't a roleplaying opportunity, but if you wanted it to be one, how would you do it?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, character-creation

I'm starting a brand new campaign (as GM) and I wanted to try to roleplay the actual character creation process. My plan is to have one on one sessions with each player where they would make narrative life choices and roll some dice which would determine the following:

1. Backstory
2. Race
3. Class
4. Sub Class
5. Stats
6. Starting Items

I was thinking of doing some sort of vision quest where the players would "re-live" pivotal moments in their life and tell me what choices they made, and could tell me what their parents were like, and through their answers it would build a back story as well as a character. But I'm not sure how I'll pull this off. I want to make the choices obvious enough that if they know what character they want to build, then they can build it, but if they want to immerse themselves in the roleplaying experience, then they'll still end up with a fully built character.

Have you ever roleplayed the character building process before? What source material did you draw from? How did the mechanics work?

Experience from 3.5e and Pathfinder is welcome as well as 5e.

Comment: There are a couple of "opinion-based" close votes, and I admit I'm on the fence about that myself (which probably means "close vote"). I suspect that there's a stackable question in here, though; I think the question would be improved by clarifying what the "best" answer would contain. For example, are you looking for an existing lifepath system that's compatible with 5e (or D&D-type high-magic sword-and-sorcery settings), general advice about creating such a system, or something else that I'm not capturing well?

Comment: My understanding is Traveller has this aspect of play in the core rules.  If that game has something like what you're looking for, referring to it in this question may improve it; i.e. how can I adapt Traveller's XXX to D&D? (maybe)